# How to failed the form if the passwords don't match?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing a register form for sending to database. However, there are two inputs of password, first is normal password and another one is to confirm password. Well, I can make jQuery to show when a user type a password which doesn't match with normal password, it will show red warning like **PASSWORD NOT MATCH**. Even though the passwords don't match, but a user can click a button to send a form into database successfully. How to stop a user from sending a form when the password don't match?

HTML is here.

```
<form id="myForm" action="registerAction" name="register" method="POST">
   <p> <label class="inputField" > Password : </label> </p>
   <p> <input class="registerField" id="textpwd" name="pwd" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Your password"/> </p>

   <p> <label class="inputField" > Confirmation Password : </label> </p>
   <p> <input class="registerField" id="textcfmpwd" name="mpwd" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();"required="required" type="password" placeholder="Confirmation password"/> <span class="warning" id="pwdWarning"> </span> </p>

   <p> <input class="registerButton" type="submit" value="REGISTER"> </p>
</form>
```

Well, to show error like **PASSWORD NOT MATCH** is below.

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").css('color', 'red');
    else
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").css('color', 'green');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#textcfmpwd").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

In conclusion, how to stop a user from sending a form when the password don't match? Any ideas?

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: ...`if($password != password in DB *or file*){  kill it }` <= PHP. Plus, use Ajax.

Comment: If JS is disabled, chances are that you will still get the same result. Use an alternate server-side solution, as already stated. You should **not** rely on JS alone.

Comment: I don't know why my questions get 3 downvotes? Am I typing wrongly?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see, okay thank you for the hints. I will check more about it. It'll be helpful if you get any tutorial for me to learn? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. http://www.freezecoders.com/2013/01/check-existing-password-and-change-password-using-ajax.html but that is `mysql_` but you can easily change that to another API. http://www.formget.com/jquery-registration-form/ - http://www.martin-gardner.co.uk/how-to-use-ajax-to-query-a-mysql-database-and-check-availability-of-a-username/ - http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php - You can further your research by Googling "ajax php database".

Comment: You're welcome and here's another http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){ 
   var bool = validatePassword();
   if(!bool)
    e.preventDefault(); // will stop the form from submitting
   else
    return true; //continue to submit form
});
```

Then for the validatePassword function

```
  function validatePassword(){
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();
    if (password != confirmPassword){
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").css('color', 'red');
        return false;
        }
    else{
       $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").css('color', 'green');
       return true;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is at the moment, you'll need a bit of code duplication.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(evt) {
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword){
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

A better solution is to refactor your `checkPasswordMatch` a bit, to have it return `true` or `false`, and work with that.

```
function passwordsMatch(){
    return $('#textpwd').val() == $('#textcfmpwd').val();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textcfmpwd").keyup(function(){
        if(!passwordsMatch()){
            $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").css('color', 'green');
        }
    });

    $('#myForm').submit(function(evt) {
       if(!passwordsMatch()){
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Note that this is only client-side scripting - you should do the same check server-side (PHP/C#/whatever).